# How to call user defined function using pyspark on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyspark

I'm using python 3.5 & spark2.2.0 on my Ubuntu 16.0
I have a python function connectDB to connect DB2.

```
def connectDB:
  import ibm_db
  conn = my Connection String
  sql = "select * from DB limit 10"
  stmt = ibm_db.exec_immediate(conn, sql)        
  while ibm_db.fetch_row(stmt) != False:    
      print ("COM_NAME : ",  ibm_db.result(stmt,3))
 return;
```

I want to call this function connectDB from my pyspark. Can you please suggest me how do I call?

Comment: Did you try `connectDB()` ?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get. Are your referring any function other than my function? I used my connectDB() function to connect DB2 from python & yes it was working

Comment: In that case, you need to explain what you meant by "I want to call this function connectDB from my pyspark."

Comment: OK. Previously I was connecting DB2 using python. But for my current project I need to connect DB2 using pyspark. As I already have function to connect DB2 using python so I thought to call that function from my pyspark module